# Proof that $\sup (a,b) = b$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I was hoping someone could check my proof.

**Thm.** Define the open interval $E := (a,b)$ in $\Bbb R$. Prove that $\sup E = b$.

**Proof.** Since $\emptyset \ne E\subset\Bbb R$ is bounded above (e.g., by $b$), $\exists\sup E$ since $\Bbb R$ possesses the $LUB$ property. Since $b$ is an upper bound, we have $x \leq b\;\forall x\in E$. By the definition of supremum, $\sup E \leq b$. For a contradiction, suppose $\sup E \neq b$. Then consider the element
$$\beta = \frac{\sup E + b}{2}.$$
So $a \leqslant \sup E < \beta < b$, so $\beta \in E$. But this implies that $\sup E$ is not an upper bound of $E$, a contradiction. Hence, $\sup E = b$.

**Update.** I have come across one additional question about thinking about the result more. If $a = b$, $(a,b) = \emptyset$, and $\sup E$ does not exist. Can I begin the proof with "without loss of generality, suppose $a < b$?"

Comment: Did you assume b<+oo ? Otherwise, that's correct

Comment: $b<\infty$ by construction as $E \in \mathbb R$ and $\infty \not\in \mathbb R$

Comment: @weijie No, it does not follow by construction and $E \in \mathbb R$ does not make sense, we have $E \subset \mathbb R$

Comment: no, you cannot say "without loss of generality, suppose a<b".

Comment: How would I deal with the issue of $(a,b)$ possibly being empty, though?

Comment: I would assume that the definition of open interval assumes that  $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and $a<b$. But if you have to include the special case "a=b" in your interval definition then the statement sup(a,b)=b is not correct for all open intervals.

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but I don't think I understand the subtlety as to why I can't say "without loss of generality." I apologize if this is obvious, but would you mind explaining more? What is this phrase reserved for?

Comment: "without loss of generality." means that all other cases can be transformed to the case you investigate , e.g by renaming, But the case a=b cannot be transformed to the case a<b. It is simple a different case with a different result.

Comment: But now I m not sure if my interpretation of "without loss of generality." is correct. Maybe one can say "if a=b the supremum does not exist so without loss of generality assume a<b" But I wouldn't use this in this way.

Comment: @JohnP. If you add an `@miracle173` to your comments the comment will be posted to my message box.

Comment: Although it is *trivial*, I think you do need to prove $(a,b)$ actually *is* bounded above by $b$.

Comment: The definition of $(a,b)$ is: Given two real numbers $a,b$ so that $a< b$ then $(a,b) = \{x| a < x < b\}$.  So we may assume by definition of $(a,b)$ that if we are *given* that the open interval $(a,b)$ *exists* that $a < b$.  ... But the reason we may assume this (that an object is given to exist and this is a condition of the definition), is *NOT* an assumption of loss of generality. Indeed $a < b$ is very *specific*. .... But it *is* an assumption we are allowed to make. (just not by wolog).

Answer (score 1):

Correct, yes.

To nitpick, I would delete the second sentence; you never use it, and in the first sentence you already asserted (in the parenthetical) that $b$ is an upper bound, so it's implied that you/your reader already know the definition.